# Парсинг постраничной навигации с phpquery

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать, чтобы парсилась постраничная навигация. Переменная `$next` содержит ссылку на след страницы.

```
function parseProduct($mysqli) {
     $products = $mysqli - > query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE Parent_sub_ID > 0  ");

     foreach($products as $tovar) {
         $product_Url = 'http://happygifts.ru'.$tovar['url'];
         $fileProduct = file_get_contents($product_Url);
         $value = phpQuery::newDocument($fileProduct);
         $products = $value - > find('.art_n_heading_wp');

         foreach($products as $product) {
             $productpq = pq($product);
             $nameProduct = $productpq - > find('.product-title') - > text();
             $artProduct = $productpq - > find('.product-number') - > text();
             $slovo1 = strtok($artProduct, " ");
             $slovo2 = strtok(" ");
             $mysqli - > query("INSERT INTO tovars (name,art) VALUES ('".$nameProduct.
                 "','".$slovo2.
                 "')");
         }
         $next = $value - > find('.catalog-pagination span.modern-page-first ') - > next() - > attr('href');
     }

 }
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под парсилась постраничная навигация? Спарсились товары которые на всех страницах или только урлы остальных страниц? Что не так сейчас? Что вы получаете в переменной next? Что хотите в ней видеть?

Comment: Спарсились товары которые на всех страницах.Переменная $next содержит ссылку на след страницы.